# numpy, understanding slicing with colon and a specific index to reduce dimension

Tags: numpy

```
 x = np.arange(24)

 y = x.reshape((2,3,4))

 array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])



 y.shape

 (2, 3, 4)
```

I'm tring to understand why `y[:, -1]` is not

```
array([[3,7,11], 
      [15,19,23]])
```

Shouldn't it go from `(2,3,4)` => `(2,3)` ?
Instead it is..

```
 y[:, -1]

 array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

 y[:, -1].shape

 (2, 4)
```

Comment: Because `-1` is at 2nd axis. You need `y[:,:,-1]` or `y[...,-1]`

Comment: `y[:, -1]` is same as `y[:, -1, :]`

Comment: oh!!.. arrgg.. Thanks